# What is the effect of storing a larger value in a grayscale png image?

Tags: java, image-processing, dct

I am trying to perform the DCT on an image with block size 8X8 in java. After performing DCT on the first block, I get the very first value as "372". 
After performing the DCT on the entire image, I wrote the values into a PNG-grayscale image.Values inside the image automatically changed.
The grayscale image will not store the value greater than 255. What will happen to the value which is greater than 255 (for eg., 372) ?

Comment: I think it will cut 255 from 372 and make 0-255 value (in your case 117).

Comment: Then how about a negative value? Will it turn it to zero?? If so in both the cases how to get back the original value? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can not get to original image after loss of information so you need to:

1. perform DCT or what ever
2. find `min,max` values from whole image
3. change range so any `pixel(x,y)=(255*(pixel(x,y)-min))/(max-min)`

   - `+/-1` or some if to clamp to the right range

After this you lose absolute values but the relative changes stays there

- for some purposes is this enough
- if you need to restore the original image
- then you need to encode min,max values to the `png` somewhere
- so add a dummy scanline(s) and encode `min,max` into first few pixels ...

restoration is then easy:

1. read `png` image
2. decode min,max
3. restore original dynamic range `pixel(x,y)=min+(((max-min)*pixel(x,y))/255)`

   - `+/-1` or some if to clamp to the right range
4. perform IDCT or what ever

Comment: The output of DCT operation will give many negative values. Suppose I do what you have mentioned in the step 3 and then to encode the min, max values somewhere in the picture, the problem is the grayscale image will not take up a negative value inside it. So how's it possible to encode a negative value inside the image?

Comment: @RohitS encoding bullet 3 changes the range to `<0,255>` and decoding bullet 3 changes the range back to `<min,max>` where `min,max` can be both positive and negative. the only problem is if `max-min>256` then you loosing precision so restored image could get a bit noisy/choppy/blurry .... you can encode `min or max`  as 4 BYTEs/pixels and use union or pointers to restore/store the `int32` value. The original image must not be 8bit grayscale but instead use 2D array of flaots,ints or whatever meets your needs....

Comment: @RohitS `3. change range ...` and `3. restore original dynamic range ...`