# How to store the DCT values in an image?

Tags: image-processing, dct

My initial task is to take a grayscale image in java, perform DCT over it (using block size 8X8) , write the DCT image. Then take the DCT image and then perform the inverse DCT over it to get back the original image.
Now the problem am facing here is , when each of the block undergoes DCT, the operation will result in many negative values and the values out of the grayscale range (for eg.,260).

How to write a grayscale image with negative values and the values out of the range? Is there any other operation need to be performed before writing the image so that all the values fall under the 0-255 range?

Comment: You should, perhaps, normalize your gray values from [0,255] to [0,1] before applying the DCT.

Comment: Sorry, can you please be little elaborative?? How do you normalize from [0,255] to [0,1]??

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the effect of storing a larger value in a grayscale png image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230588/what-is-the-effect-of-storing-a-larger-value-in-a-grayscale-png-image)

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions instead add [edits] to your original question or add comments if you want to add something (edits also boost your position in questions list)